# Can anyone tell me a Skype alternative?

Tags: windows, video, wifi-calling, assistive-technology

There are a lot but they don't have screen-sharing, 
I want a one with screen-sharing, for windows and free. Thanks

Comment: See https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2180/how-should-i-ask-about-getting-a-software-recommendation/2181#2181 for details about how to ask for software recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

I use the website [alternativeto.net](https://alternativeto.net) when searching for alternatives to certain software. It allows you to filter by platform (macOS, Windows, Linux) and also by licence (ie. open-source/commerical-paid/free-as-in-beer).

Here is their current list of recommendations for alternatives to Skype for macOS and Windows: https://alternativeto.net/software/skype/

1. [Discord](https://discordapp.com)
2. [Telegram](https://telegram.org) (no screen sharing currently)
3. [Tox](https://tox.chat)
4. [Slack](https://slack.com)
5. [Hangouts](https://hangouts.google.com)

There are also web-based alternatives like [deadsimplescreensharing.com](https://www.deadsimplescreensharing.com), which doesn't require any app or plugin to be installed.

Comment: Nice to learn about Nice to learn about https://alternativeto.net website.

Comment: @NimeshNeema there's also a similar, new website https://www.slant.co - but I don't like it as much.

Comment: @NimeshNeema Product Hunt also do it [like this](https://www.producthunt.com/alternatives/skype-meetings) but again, not as good as alternative.to IMHO

Answer (score 0):

[Zoom.us](https://zoom.us) is a cross platform alternative with enhanced features such as screen sharing, remote control and multi participant meetings.

Mobile apps are also available for major platforms. The free version has majority of [features](https://zoom.us/pricing) which are enough to cover majority of use cases.

Comment: Nimesh Nima,  thanks but can you ellaborate on what "remote control" means

Comment: In a screen sharing session, remote control lets you take control of the participants computer, similar to a VNC session.

Comment: Does it have individual video calling option as well? I mean (1 on 1 session)

Comment: Yes. That's the most basic form of meeting.